# valor do input não aparece em POST

Tags: php, html

Olá, estou com um problema meio bobo mas é o seguinte: quando dou submit, via post, todos os valores dos inputs do form estão corretos mas percebi que apenas o valor desse input não aparece. Não consegui identificar o problema.

**Input que não aparece no post:**

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_user" name="nome_user" value="<?php echo $result['nome_user'];?>" disabled>`

para verificar os valores em POST usei:

`print("<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente seja por conta do atributo: disabled.

substitua pelo atributo reandoly!

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_user" name="nome_user" value="<?php echo $result['nome_user'];?>" reandoly>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, sequer passou pela minha cabeça! Muito obrigada.